# Customising ticks and scaling the graph so it matches - Chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to be able to create a graph with custom ticks, which I have already done. However, [these ticks scale with to the graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk0bK.png) whereas I want the opposite, I want the graph to scale to the ticks. In other words, I want an even amount of space between all of my ticks.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

This is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/9a0cfae0/3/

JavaScript:

```
var ticks = [11000, 10000, 7000, 3000, 1000, 500, 100];
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [6000, 5000, 8000, 2000, 10000, 3500, 6000, 2000, 4000, 6000]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false,
          min: ticks[ticks.length - 1],
          max: ticks[0]
        },
        afterBuildTicks: function(scale) {
          scale.ticks = ticks;
          return;
        },
        beforeUpdate: function(oScale) {
          return;
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: Your graph looks correct to me.  It would not make sense to have equal space between your ticks because your ticks are at different intervals.  For example, the space between your first 2 ticks is 400, however the space between your 3rd and 4th tick is 2000 (this is 5 times larger than the first 2 ticks).  Make sense?

Comment: Yes... but I want to be able to split the graph in half - because I have some data that is in the 1000's and others than range from 0-10. These HAVE to be on the same graph but I need it so that data points that range from 0-10 are distinguishable. Hope you can see my predicament and this makes sense :)

Comment: I see what you mean.  Unfortunately, chart.js cannot do this and I can't think of anyway to build it in on top of chart.js (I have dones TONS of customizations of chart.js).  Sorry about that :(

Comment: For anyone who might come across this: I think one could do something similar using two separate Y-axes. Chart.js will draw all the lines together (over one another, in fact) but scale each line to the axis it's tied to. It won't work if each line has a wide range of values, but for separate lines which have to both show on the same graph, it might work.